# Javascript: get DOM element's outerHTML *with* value

Tags: javascript, dom

I observe that `outerHTML` for an input doesn't seem to reflect updated values/checks in form inputs. Is there a way for me to get `outerHTML` for an entire page and have the values/checks included?

To illustrate, I have some form inputs:

```html
<input id="a" type="text" />
<input id="b" type="text" value="ham" />
```

I can change the values of the inputs, but the outerHTML does not change.

```js
document.getElementById('a').value = 'cheese';
document.getElementById('b').value = 'biscuit';
document.getElementById('a').outerHTML // => <input id="a" type="text" />
document.getElementById('b').outerHTML // => <input id="b" type="text" value="ham" />
```

If I create a new element and add it to the DOM, `document.body.outerHTML` holds the new element but still none of the updated values:

```js
const c = document.createElement('input');
c.id = 'c';
c.type = 'text';
document.body.appendChild(c);
document.body.outerHTML /* => <body>
<input id="a" type="text">
<input id="b" type="text" value="ham">
<input id="c" type="text"></body> */
```

Comment: use `setAttribute` instead of setting properties on the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change attribute of element to change outerHTML. Try this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a"));

document.getElementById("a").setAttribute("value", "new value");

console.log(document.getElementById("a"));
```

```html
<input id="a" type="text" />
<input id="b" type="text" value="ham" />
```